# Org-drill not working with verbs

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

has someone come across the same issue maybe:

org-drill is a great package for spacemacs and works quite well out of the box for one- and twosided cards as well as clozes.

However, I can for the life of me not figure out how to use org-drill with verbs. the example file `spanish.org` (see [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-drill.html)) does provide a `:DRILL_CARD_TYPE: spanish_verb` and according to `org-drill.el` I would expect that running `M-x org-drill` drills verbs too.

However, on my spacemacs installation (develop branch 0.300.x) org-drill will not run these verbs.

Has somebody come across the same issue and found a possible solution? Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was related to this question:

[org-drill isn't letting me drill](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/org-drill-isnt-letting-me-drill?rq=1)

org-drill would not recognize the verbs - even if PROPERTIES were set right - as sth to drill. So inserting a comment `#spanish_verb` right after the

```
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BLABLABLA:
    :END:
    #spanish_verb
```

worked for me.